# Testing React "PersistLogin" Component stuck

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this simple test:

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('renders headline', async () => {
    render(<App />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });
    expect(screen.getByText('Welcome to Mentor Blog')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And this PersistLogin component:

```
export const PersistLogin = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const refresh = useRefreshToken();
  const { user } = useApplicationState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const verifyRefreshToken = async () => {
      try {
        await refresh();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } finally {
        isMounted && setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    !user?.accessToken ? verifyRefreshToken() : setIsLoading(false);

    return () => isMounted = false;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <Outlet />}
    </>
  );
};
```

The test fails, rendering the PersistLogin component but not moving forward, so I get this in the console:

```
<divclass="menuItem">
          Mentor Blog
        </div>
        <div
          class="menuItem"
        >
          Log in
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        Loading...
      </p>
    </div>
```

I'm sure there's a way to handle this. Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT:
I was able to make it pass by changing the code to:

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('renders headline', async () => {
    render(<App />);
    const element = await screen.findByText('Welcome to Mentor Blog');

    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

...since "getBy" does not accept "async" as per the Testing Library docs:
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/

But now I got this dirty console message:
[image]

New question is, is my solution correct technically? How will I then handle this console error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me, without being able to see your app context, etc. You're getting that error from this:

```js
catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Axios throws an error when a 4XX or 500 status code is received. You're getting error 401 Unauthorized from your login endpoint.

I don't know what your `useRefreshToken()` hook looks like but you could handle the error quite simply:

```js
const verifyRefreshToken = async () => {
  try {
    await refresh();
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error?.response?.status) {
      case "401":
        alert("You are unauthorized!");
        break;
      case "403":
        // do something
        break;
      case "500":
        // do something
        break;
      default:
        alert("An unknown server error occured!");
    }
  } finally {
    isMounted && setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
```